# Linking Marketo Custom Object to Lead via SOAP

Tags: soap, marketo

How do I link a custom object created via Marketo's SOAP API to an existing lead?

Answer (score 1):

In your custom object, you can define one of the fields as a 'link'.

In the web interface , when you select 'link', it reloads the dialog and gives you the option to select the linked object type (Lead) and the field to link with (ID).

When you create an object using the SOAP API with a link field like this, you can give the custom object your lead ID to link it.